# How to store a radio button selection?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been learning html forms and php.  I have a form that has multiple choice answers with radio buttons.  It works fine.  However, the radio button does not remain selected in the form.  I'd like for it to remain selected as I post the correct answer so they can see what they originally selected.

Is there an attribute or action that will keep the radio button selected?

```
<form action="testit.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['submit']))
 echo " keep selected item marked  </br>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you include a snippet of your code in your question?

Comment: You can select Bike or Car, but when the form reloads from the ACTION calling the same file, the selection is reset to blank bullets.

Comment: Can I use a $_SESSION var to keep something that checks the previous response and resets the radio button to checked?

Comment: Please add code snippets in your question itself. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: *"Can I use a $_SESSION var to keep something that checks the previous response and resets the radio button to checked?"* - Yes

Comment: What value do I need to keep the bullet on?

Answer (score 0):

You should after your post return to the page (or something where the radio buttons are visible).

Then you can check the value. If its the posted value, set attribute `checked="checked"` and you are done.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" <?php echo (isset($_POST["vehicle"]) && $_POST["vehicle"] == "Bike" ? "checked='checked'" : ""); ?>> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" <?php echo (isset($_POST["vehicle"]) && $_POST["vehicle"] == "Car" ? "checked='checked'" : ""); ?>> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: changed it to above.  then added a check to see which value was selected.  Then, I restated the <input type= statement with checked inserted.  Doesn't work any different.  I'm just confused.  sorry.

Comment: On a side note, why do you put a ? when you check for the $_POST. I've never seen that syntax.  (told you I was a newbie)   i.e,  $_POST["vehicle"] == "Bike" ? ...

Comment: @JanetMcCready the ? and : are short expression of if else. So when POST is made, and POST value is similar as Bike/Car, its true and will add checked=checked. Else its empty. I havent tested the code. I just want to put you in the right direction. PHP_SELF means post to the same page. So first no checkbox is selected. When make a POST, the page goes to its own, when value is checked it will be checked again. Make sure you using in the <form method="POST" action=.....>

Comment: I checked the value and added it to a session var. Then, checked the var before putting the <input line out.  If the value has been selected, I use the <input line that says CHECKED.  ELSE, the <input line that doesn't have checked.  Not pretty but...    thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax help.  I'll try and start using that too.  :-)

Comment: I want to thank you again eL-Prova!  This has saved me a TON of time.  My checkbox'es are working great!!!!!